# Which profiles I should choose for code signing

Tags: xcode, code-signing

I want to distribute my app. So I created the App ID and the provisioning profiles required for development and distribution. Now, I want to set the code signing identity in Xcode. However, I'm confused to what choose for the following fields:
[image]

When I click the drop down, I get the following options:
[image]

The omitted space is my name and the app's name. So which one should I choose to which field? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In summarize form:

Development profile is chosen when you want to test your app on profile registered devices, while Distribution profile is needed when you are going to archive your code for submission on app store.

Comment: okay got that part but which one of the second picture should i use for each field of the first picture? if i want to use the "iPhone developer" ,in (recommended), it will point to my app's App Id. and choosing "iphone distribution: MyName" does the same. so does it matter which one i should choose? and what about "Any iOS SDK"?

Comment: You will be choosing iPhone Distribution in Release, and iPhone Dev in Debug. You will be selecting provisional profile according to their purpose.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to distribute, the standard way to do this is through the "Archive" process. Make sure "iOS Device" is your target, and click Product->Archive. This will build the project without code signing. Then Organizer should load (if it doesn't, bring it up manually using Window->Organizer and go to the Archive tab).

You'll see the latest archive in there - select it and click 'Distribute'. Follow that process and it'll show you valid distribution profiles to chose from based on your distribution route.

Comment: but shouldn't i set the code sign identity fields before archiving?

Comment: You shouldn't need to. If you want to edit the preferences in the screenshot you provided, it's best to use the automatic profile selectors. For Release, it'd be 'Distribution' and Debug it'd be 'Development' (typically).